# Questions regarding dynamics

Tags: limits, dynamical-systems, inverse-function

$Let (F, X) = $ dynamical system

**Part 1:** 
Prove that if $F(a) = a$ such that a $\epsilon$ X (a is a fixed point of F), then the basin of attraction of $a$ , $A_a$ is non-empty.

Def'n: 
Let (F, X) = dynamical system and let a $\epsilon$ X. The **basin of attraction**

of a is the set $A_a$ = {y $\epsilon$ X : $\lim_{a\to \infty} F^{n}y = a$}

*Should I use proof by contradiction here?*

**Part 2:**
Fix b $\epsilon$ X. Prove that if R $\subseteq$ $A_{y}$(basin of attractn)then $F(R^{-1})$ $\subseteq$ $A_{y}$.

Comment: Could you please check against the original for typographical errors? The running index in the definition of $A_a$ is $n$, in part 2 I'm quite sure that $b=y$ and that it is not the inverse of the point set, but of the function.

Comment: Please tell more of your own efforts and how far you got. Is part 1 trivially true as $a\in A_a$?